# Mostrar contenido de una lista en mi body, con c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Buen dia, sencillamente no es un problema o error, mas que todo es querer visualizar una lista dentro de una clase Datos, utlizando postman como prueba, les muestro las siguientes clases utilizadas.

Class Datos.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiReportesEncuestasADENBPO.Contracts.AccesoDTO.Request
{
    public class Datos
    {
        public class Zona {
            private string codZona { get; set; }
            private string descripcion { get; set; }
            private int flkActivo { get; set; }

            public Zona(string codZona, string descripcion, int flkActivo)
            {
                this.codZona = codZona;
                this.descripcion = descripcion;
                this.flkActivo = flkActivo;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Zona{" + "codZona=" + codZona 
                                + ", descripcion=" + descripcion 
                                + ", flkActivo=" + flkActivo + '}';
            }
        }

        public string nombreUsuario { get; set; }
        public string apellidoUsuario { get; set; }
        public string codCargo { get; set; }
        public string passUsuario { get; set; }
        public List<Zona> codZona { get; set; }
        public string tipoAdm { get; set; }
        public string correo { get; set; }

        public Datos(string nombreUsuario, string apellidoUsuario, string codCargo, string passUsuario, List<Zona> codZona, string tipoAdm, string correo)
        {
            this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
            this.apellidoUsuario = apellidoUsuario;
            this.codCargo = codCargo;
            this.passUsuario = passUsuario;
            this.codZona = codZona;
            this.tipoAdm = tipoAdm;
            this.correo = correo;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Datos{" + "nombreUsuario=" + nombreUsuario
                            + ", apellidoUsuario=" + apellidoUsuario
                            + ", codCargo=" + codCargo
                            + ", passUsuario=" + passUsuario
                            + ", codZona=" + codZona
                            + ", tipoAdm=" + tipoAdm
                            + ", correo=" + correo + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Clase AccesoService.cs

```
public class AccesoService : IAccesoService
    {

        private readonly IAccesoRepository _accesoRepository;
        private readonly Validacion _validar;
        private readonly Encriptador _encriptador;
        private readonly IMClienteZonaRepository _mClientesZonaRepository;

        public AccesoService(IAccesoRepository accesoRepository, Validacion validar, Encriptador encriptador, IMClienteZonaRepository mClientesZonaRepository)
        {
            _accesoRepository = accesoRepository;
            _validar = validar;
            _encriptador = encriptador;
            _mClientesZonaRepository = mClientesZonaRepository;
        }

        public async Task<Datos> obtener_usuario(Usuario usuario)
        {
            MClientesUsuario clientesUsuario = null;
            try
            {
                string idUsuario = usuario.codUsuario;
                string idUsuarioDesencriptado = _encriptador.Decrypt(idUsuario, "");
                if (idUsuarioDesencriptado == null)
                {
                    throw new ExceptionAdenbpo(new Mensaje("", "No existe el usuario", AuxMessageException.TIPO_MENSAJE_ERROR));
                }

                clientesUsuario = await _accesoRepository.obtener_usuario_x_id(idUsuarioDesencriptado);
                string nombreUsuario = clientesUsuario.NOMBRES;
                string apellidoUsuario = clientesUsuario.APELLIDOS;
                string codCargoUsuario = clientesUsuario.CODCARGO;
                string contraseniaUsuario = clientesUsuario.PASSUSUARIO;
                string codZonaUsuario = clientesUsuario.CODZONA;
                string tipoAdmUsuario = clientesUsuario.TIPOADM;
                string correoUsuario = clientesUsuario.CORREO;

                Datos datos = null;
                List<Datos.Zona> zonas = new List<Datos.Zona>();
                if (codCargoUsuario == AuxCargo.COD_CARGO_GERENTE_ZONAL_CREDITOS || codCargoUsuario == AuxCargo.COD_CARGO_ADMINISTRADOR)
                {
                    List<MClientesZona> listClientesZonas = await _mClientesZonaRepository.obtener_zona_x_id(codZonaUsuario);

                    foreach (MClientesZona clienteZona in listClientesZonas)
                    {
                        string codclienteZona = clienteZona.CODZONA;
                        string descripcionZona = clienteZona.DESCRIPCION;
                        int flkActivoCliente = clienteZona.FLKACTIVO;
                        zonas.Add(new Datos.Zona(codclienteZona, descripcionZona, flkActivoCliente));
                    }
                }
                if (clientesUsuario == null)
                {
                    throw new ExceptionAdenbpo(new Mensaje("", "Lo siento, no se pudo obtener al usuario", AuxMessageException.TIPO_MENSAJE_ERROR));
                }

                //OBTENER POR LISTA LA ZONA DE CADA ZONAL
                datos = new Datos(
                    nombreUsuario,
                    apellidoUsuario,
                    codCargoUsuario,
                    contraseniaUsuario,
                    zonas,
                    tipoAdmUsuario,
                    correoUsuario
                );
                return datos;
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

La respuesta que recibo utilizando Postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra la respuesta estoy tratando de mostrar información que contiene esa lista, pero no encuentro soluciones.

Saludos.

Comment: Haz que tus entidades sean `[Serializable]` y luego serializas la lista usando el framework `Json.NET`. Lo que colocas en la imagen es un `Json` solo debes deserializar. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/

Comment: buen día, me podrías mostrar un pequeño ejemplo de implementación.